# Domain objects, entity objects and repository with LINQ expression

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, generics, automapper

I have WPF MVVM application, where entity objects are generated using Code First from Database. Then I have domain objects, where business logic is. I have generic repository which returns domain objects (AutoMapped from entity objects). Is there any way to easily convert domain object predicate (???) to entity predicate? I want to avoid exposing entity objects in MainRepository if possible.

```
Class GenericRepository(Of TEntity As Class, TContext As DbContext)
  Function Select(predicate As Func(Of TEntity, Boolean) As IList(Of TEntity)
    Return context.Set(Of TEntity)().Where(predicate).ToList()
  End Function
End Class

Class MainRepository
  Private _repository As New GenericRepository(Of ProductEntity, ProductionContext)
  Sub SelectProducts(???) As IList(Of ProductDomainObject)
    Dim entities = _repository.Select(???)
    Return (AutoMap entities to domain objects)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should write mapping layer on your own in this case. Also keep in mind that in this case when you pass entities back to repository, you have to remap their values to attached db entities, so that changes would get to EntityStateTracker. For data convertion to domain entities you can use automapper, valueinjecter or similar. Overall this question is really wide.

Comment: I am not solving mapping, I am solving how to convert entity predicate to domain object predicate. Because EF creates SQL query based on this predicate, otherwise it returns all rows. You do not understand my question.

Comment: Did not realize you were talking about expression conversion. I am afraid there is no simple way to do this. You can probably switch to Criteria or Query Object patterns, make methods without predicates or do predicates work with type of your Persistence Model, not Domain Model - you will need to pass your Persistence Model type as generic argument to your generic repository, which is quite dirty.

Comment: Do you have example or link to this criteria/query object patterns? I agree that passing persistence model to domain model stinks.

Comment: Here's an example of Criteria for NHibernate : http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html , it should give you high level idea. You will define criteria for your domain object, and then inside repository you can transform it to your where filter. Query object will just split out all your possible queries over repository so that you would not have huge number of different filters in one repository - Query Object impersonates 1 repository operation.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I wouldn't worry about all that encapsulation and get rid of your layer objects: https://vimeo.com/131633177

However, if you absolutely insist on all this layering, AutoMapper will also convert expressions for you:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource)

An expression defined in the Entity can be converted automatically to the domain model. However, your example needs to accept an `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`, not `Func<TEntity, bool>` for this to work. Entity Framework only deals with expressions, not any random delegate passed in.

Comment: I like this answer. So having only entities with validation attributes and repository with basic Select,Insert,Update,Delete methods is OK for you?

Comment: I go one step further, my commands have validation, not entities. I don't validate state *after* the state has been changed, but *before*.

Comment: I am not sure if you realize that I am creating desktop WPF application, not web application. Using data binding, users are noticed to data input errors immediately, command always saves valid data.

Comment: So why do your entities have validation? In any case, I still do the same thing on MVVM apps, get rid of the layers.

Comment: Where else should be validation? If in view models (commands), then there will be as much duplicit validation code as count of view models. Entities are my only layer, no more domain objects as you assured me.